# Duende.BFF doesn't bring bff specific management data

Tags: asp.net, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly, duende

I followed the procedure in:
[Building Blazor WASM client applications in Duende Software](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v6/quickstarts/7_blazor/)

as the documentation exposes, in [Session Management Endpoints](https://docs.duendesoftware.com/identityserver/v5/bff/session/management/)

I am supposed to receive these items:

```
bff:session_expires_in
bff:session_state
bff:logout_url
```

but I receive only bff:session_expires_in.
There is any configuration needed to get the missing items?